# Compare the value of clicked element with the correct answear

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I need the handle change() method to compare between the clicked button in the Buttons Component and the correct answer and update the count state or the count state falls state but in my case doesn't work in either case

```js
import Buttons from "./buttons";
class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            Behave: false,
            count: 0,
            countFalls: 0,
            Arr: [],
            timer: 0,
        }
        this.HandleChange = this.HandleChange.bind(this)
    }

    HandleChange() {
        for (let i = 0; i < Split.length; i++) {
            if (Split[i] === ChoiceFour) {
                this.setState(Prevstate => ({
                    count: Prevstate.count + 1,
                    arr: !Prevstate.arr
                }))
            }
            else {
                this.setState(Prevstate => ({
                    countFalls: Prevstate.countFalls + 1,
                    arr: !Prevstate.arr
                }))
            }

        }


    }

    render() {

        const Game = () => {
            return (
                <div className="border">
                    <Container className="Buttons">
                        <Row>
                            <Col><Buttons dices={Split} click={this.HandleChange} /></Col>
                        </Row>

            )
        }
```

Comment: Find a basic react tutorial... There's way too much wrong with this code...

Comment: that's not all the code that's the not working part